# Ayuda sobre Jquery Validation Plugin

Tags: jquery, bootstrap, jquery-validate

Tengo el siguiente código HTML el cual me muestra un cuadro de texto:

```
 <div class="form-group empresa_rfc">
                                <label for="empresa_rfc" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><p class="text-left">RFC: (*)</p></label>
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="empresa_rfc" name="empresa_rfc" placeholder="RFC" >
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Estoy usando Bootrap 3.3.7. Y luego tengo esta validacion con el Plugin Jquery Validate de https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

```
$("#form_empresa").validate({
            focusCleanup: true,
            rules: {
                empresa_rfc: { required: true }
            },
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator){
                var errors = validator.numberOfInvalids();
                if (errors){
                    var message = errors == 1
                        ? 'You missed 1 field. It has been highlighted'
                        : 'You missed ' + errors + ' fields. They have been highlighted';
                    swal({
                        title:"Error:",
                        text: message,
                        type: "error",
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#d33',
                        confirmButtonText: "Corregir"
                    });
                    //console.log(message);
                }
            }
        });
```

EL código anterior me muestra y señala el campo que no ha sido completado, y me muestra un `alert` indicándome los errores contenidos en 'message'. Mi duda es, ¿como puedo afectar al

```
<div class="form-group empresa_rfc">
```

y agregarle la clase 'has-error' de Bootstrap para que pueda señalar ese campo en especifico? En concreto debería quedar así:

```
<div class="form-group empresa_rfc has-error">
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo a mano: $('form-group').addClass('has-error'); en caso que entre en el if de errors y $('form-group').removeClass('has-error'); en el caso que no tenga errores

Comment: Y en el caso cuando tengo varios div form-group, como sabria a cual referirme de manera dinamica? De antemano, gracias

Comment: Tienes unas reglas, seguramente en el parametro validator te venga que regla se esta aplicando.

Tienes el div, con la clase empresa_rfc que es igual a la regla que tienes definida, con esto si consigues sacar la regla que se esta aplicando podrías hacer algo como:

 $(validator.regla).addClass('has-error');

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar el atributo `messages:{}` del plugin, quedando algo así:

```
rules: {
  RFC: {
    required: true
  }
},
messages: {
  RFC: {
    required: ""
  }
}
```

Eso hará que se marque el `input` que esta incorrecto o le hace falta valor, pero a **consecuencia le agregara un pequeño espacio debajo del `input` que es el valor del mensaje**.